# Loading asynchronous parse data inside html using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, parse-platform, javascript-databinding

I am trying a quick test to debug why some of my code isn't working as expected.

I have a controller named `testCtrl` and a service `myService` . In the service, I am trying to get data from Parse and once I have the data, I am trying to load this data into my frontend html.

Here's the code:

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope,myService) {
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();

$scope.username = currentUser.getUsername();
$scope.test = "ths";
var promise1 = myService.getEvaluatorData();
promise1.then(function(response){
    $scope.results2 = response;
    console.log(response);
    });
});

app.factory('myService', function(){
 return {
   getAllData: function($scope){
      getEvaluatorData($scope);
   },

   getEvaluatorData: function(){

       var evaluators = Parse.Object.extend("Evaluators");
       query = new Parse.Query(evaluators);

       return query.find({
          success: function(results){
            angular.forEach(results, function(res){

                console.log("Looped"); //this is just to verify that the then call below is executed only after all array objects are looped over.
            });

          } ,
          error: function(error){

          }
       });
   }
  }
});
```

Here's the html code where I want to display the data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
{{test}}

{{results2}}
</body>
</html>
```

The `results2` don't load up in the html.

Here is the console log.

```
testParse.js:46 This is done
2015-07-10 15:28:32.539testParse.js:46 This is done
2015-07-10 15:28:32.540testParse.js:46 This is done
2015-07-10 15:28:32.541testParse.js:46 This is done
2015-07-10 15:28:32.542testParse.js:56 Returning result as promised [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Comment: Imo you completly messed it.You should use angular router or directives - depends on purpose.

Comment: @PawełSmołka sorry I am a beginner to angularjs, can you please elaborate? Thanks very much!

Comment: If you want custom-views use ng-view. If you want to put custom caluclated content use directives, can be mixed with factory functionality. You got directives description in angular api-reference. If you read this you will find your solution. 
I am too busy with my newborn today to write more :/

Comment: @PawełSmołka Thanks for your help. You definitely have some clues for me. I will investigate it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `return` data from your service and pass it to your controller.  For ex:

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope, myService) {
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    $scope.username = currentUser.getUsername();
    $scope.test = "this";
    myService.getEvaluatorData().then(function (response) {
        console.log('response', response);
        $scope.results2 = response;
    });
});

app.factory('myService', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        getEvaluatorData: function () {
            var evaluators = Parse.Object.extend("Evaluators");
            var query = new Parse.Query(evaluators);

            return query.find({
                success: function (results) {
                    return results;
                },
                error: function (error) {
                   return error;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Also, no point in calling `this.getEvaluatorData($scope)` in my opinion, when you can call the `getEvaluatorData` method directly

Comment: Here is an example of how I have used Parse https://gist.github.com/jforaker/e5040d19b9e69e44769b  Hope it helps

Comment: Also you might want to initialize an empty array first, like:  `$scope.results2 = []`

Answer (score 0):

use $rootScope.result2 instead of $scope.result2